# javascript format time variable into Hour and Minute only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this variable which has for example "12:12:12"

How can I format this into "12:12" only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have Date Object you can do :

**Code:**

```
dateFormat(new Date(), "mm/dd/yy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

**Output**

```
"05/30/14, 11:46:03 AM"
```

**Notations** :-

```
mm -> month
dd -> date
yy -> year
h  -> hour
MM -> minutes
ss -> seconds
TT -> AM/PM
```

**Note** :- If You dont want the current date time Pass the Date time object in place of new Date();

Hope this Helps you